# Replacing decayed array with a pointer to array resulting in segmentation fault

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, pointers, segmentation-fault

I was trying to loop through an array using pointers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    char name[]{ "Abhi" };

    for (char* ptr_c{ name }; ptr_c != (ptr_c + std::size(name)); ++ptr_c) {
        std::cout << *ptr_c;
    } 

    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

This results in: `Error: Segmentation fault core dumped`

However, in the `for` loop's condition testing:

```
 for (char* ptr_c{ name }; ptr_c != (ptr_c + std::size(name)); ++ptr_c)
                                     ^^^^^^
```

Replcaing `ptr_c` with `name` makes it work. Why?
Shouldn't `name` decay to `ptr_c` anyway?

Comment: `ptr_c != (ptr_c + std::size(name))` will always be true, if `std::size(name)` is non-zero.   So your loop is infinite and , since every iteration access `*ptr_c` and then increments `ptr_c`, your code is accessing data past the end of `name`.   Whereas `name + std::size(name)` is the same for every loop iteration - and eventually `ptr_c` will be equal to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> ptr_c != ptr_c + std::size(name)
> ```

This condition is never false. If you add a non-zero number to a pointer, the resulting pointer will never equal the original pointer. Hence, the infinite loop overflows the array.

> Shouldn't name decay to ptr_c anyway?

No. `name` always decays to a pointer to the first element. `ptr_c` only starts as the first element, but after the first iteration, it points to other elements.

Comment: oh thanks i get it now! ```ptr_c``` is being incremented, so after the first iteration it no longer acts as a pointer to the first element of ```name```